# "object requested" in a calculus

Tags: excel, vba

The code below leads to an "Object requested" error. I tried to change Dim Z As Range into Dim Z As Double but with the same result.
Any hint on why this is happening and how to get a solution would be very welcome.

```
Dim Z1 As Range
Dim Z As Range

Set Z1 = Wb_Optim.Sheets(1).Cells(n + 1, "D")
Set Z = Z1.Value2 - 10
```

Comment: If `Z` is equal to `Z1.Value2 - 10`, `Z` should not be a `Range` but a `Double` for sure, but without `Set`.

Comment: You can't set a range of a double.  and you do not set a Double.  `Dim Z as Double` and `Z = Z1.Value2 - 10` No `Set`

Comment: Working Thank you. I understand.